# Javascript to change button text

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

i need a javascript function to be called on certain button click, upon that click the button name will change. 
ie,

```
<input type=button id = button1 value=boy onclick=function(boy,girl)>
```

i need the javascript function to take 2 parameters and check if the value of the button is the first paramter, then the value will become the 2nd and vice versa.

so if i press the button and it says BOY, it will become Girl
and if i press the button and it says Girl it will become boy!
using javascript please thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but by `getById` function showed below you will have a portable function to access to DOM elements by `id` :

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getById(a) {
           if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(a)) {
              return document.getElementById(a)
           } else {
              if (document.all && document.all(a)) {
                 return document.all(a)
              } else {
                 if (document.layers && document.layers[a]) {
                    return document.layers[a]
                 } else {
                    return false
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        function myfunc()
        {
        getById("button1").value =(getById("button1").value=="boy")?"girl":"boy";
        }
    </script>
<head>
</head>
<input type="button" value="boy" id="button1" onclick="myfunc();" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/w9ed8/

or:

```
<input type=button id = button1 value=boy onclick="changeMe(this)">

<script>
function changeMe(obj){
  if(obj.value == "boy"){
     obj.value = "girl"
   }else{
     obj.value = "boy"
   }
}
</script>
```

Or

```
<input type=button id = button1 value=boy onclick="changeMe(this, 'boy' , 'girl')">

<script>
function changeMe(obj , param1 , param2){
  if(obj.value == param1 ){
     obj.value = param2
   }else{
     obj.value = param1 
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: only working for boy and girl and the function is not working as asked :) he asked for a function which will compute at least 2 parameters :)

Comment: Well I think ahead and I know y he asked for 2 params, but it is not necessary... (-:

Comment: so he can use this function only on a button that has the value boy or girl, because it is not "neccessary" ;) if someone don't mind to write unreusable code this is pretty fine I guess ;)

Comment: @Pranav you can take my code and use it on any button created and just edit the function call on the button itself and it will work.. fatnjazzy's code will only work for buttons with the value boy or girl, so fatnjazzy's solution is not reusable for buttons with a value "male" or "female", "single" or "married".. and so on

Comment: Well, you can see that this function is really really solving minor issue.... doesn't matter i think

Comment: @walialu:-ya right.. i think yours code is more generic in nature. +1 for you.

Comment: @Walialu - ok, added as an option in my answer (-:

Comment: @Walialu so -1 me if you want... exploding the Atom

Comment: I am not downvoting you for just copying my answer ;) may you be happy with that :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var foo = function(a,b,c){
  if(a.value==b){
    a.value=c;
  }
  else{
    a.value=b;
  }
};
```

and for the button

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="boy" onclick="foo(this,"boy","girl")">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type=button id=button1 value=boy onclick='test(this,boy,girl)'>
<script>
      function test(Sender,boy,girl){
        Sender.value = Sender.value == boy ? girl : boy;
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function change()
{
 if((document.getElementById("button1").value)=="Boy")
 {
  document.getElementById("button1").value="Girl"
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("button1").value="Boy"
 }
}
```